# How to get Android Device GPS id(Like IMEI number)

Tags: android

In my android application i want to get my android device GPS Id(Like IMEI number). I don't know whether it is possible or not.Please help me on this part.

Thanks,
Android Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Manifest file add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

In your code add

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imeiNumber=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: Question was about the GPS ID and not IMEI ID

Answer (score -1):

You will get  the IMEI Number of your Android Mobile Requires Permission: 
READ_PHONE_STATE

```
 TelephonyManager teleManager = (TelephonyManager) context .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String IMEI = teleManager.getDeviceId();
```